# Is this clearly expressed: "The real power is information"

Tags: word-choice, clarity

I want to say that information is the real power in the world. I want to say it in one clean (short) sentence. Is the following good enough? (My mother language isn't English.)

> The real power is information.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I think the way you're saying it is fine. It's concise, unambiguous, and to the point. That being said, however, it's [not a terribly original statement](http://www.google.com/search?q=information+is+power&ie=UTF-8#sclient=psy&hl=en&source=hp&q=%22information+is+power%22&aq=f&aqi=g1g-c1g3&aql=&oq=&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.&fp=44b3839bd44fe786).

Comment: I concur, it is fine as is; the more common expression is "information is power". As Kelly suggests this expression/sentiment is somewhat cliche, so either way I might try to elaborate a bit :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

what about

> Information **IS** Power

Comment: That's good if you want to be completely unoriginal.

Answer (score 3):

I always wonder when I see questions like these. The person asking says, "I want to say that information is the real power in the world."

How about you say:

> Information is the real power in the world.

Answer (score 3):

"The real power is information" only really makes sense if it's being used to contradict what is normally considered to be "the real" power. For example:

- "Some say true power in business is money, but the real power is information."
- "Magic beans are considered by most to be the source of power in business. This is not true. Information is the real power."

Otherwise, you're better off using "Information is power" (even though it's a bit trite and clichéd).

Answer (score 0):

I think this is too short and vague. You mention 'real power', as opposed to what . . . imaginary power? And what sort of power? The power to act, buy or sell? Combining vague 'power' combined with the general word 'information' creates more questions than answers.

Your sentiment seems to be along the line of the phrase "time is money" - yet this phrase is creates a much clearer picture because the reader can relate time to money.

Assuming that 'power' means 'ability', you could try something like: "Power is useless without information" - a very relevant statement in today's economic and geopolitical state of affairs, yet I suggest you replace the word 'power' with something more specific to create a clearer picture.